# Magento shows old website after migration

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have migrated a Magento website to a live server, but it shows the old website on my PC and when I open in my mobile phone, it shows new website. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Clear cache on admin.

Comment: cleared cache but nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some actions to try:

- Clear your browser cache.
- Try clearing the cookies.
- Try in Incognito mode if your browser have it.
- Try with a different browser.
- Try in a different network (the DNS could still be propagating the required info).
- Try requesting an URL with some additional query string parameter, to avoid caching by URL. For example, if your site is in http://example.com/, try visiting http://example.com/?testing=1
- Make sure you had not pointed your domain to your local IP in your development computer.